# Adding OR to my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have the "Ever Expanding LINQ Query"... I found myself having to tack on a number of parameters and I'm getting crosseyed.  I have this:

```
 var ud = db.Updates
   .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false)&&(c.Status.Equals(("Pending"))))
   .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
   .Select(x => x
      .OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp)
      .First())
   .ToList();
```

And I need to add an OR to the "c.Status.Equals" to test for multiple string values... such as "Pending" || "Rejected" what's the right way/place to do this?

Thanks very much for any assistance!

Comment: Why not `c => !c.Sold && c.Status == "Pending"`?  Your really don't need to use `Equals` here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to consider storing an array of values to see if any of the constraints are met :

```
// Store all of the statuses you need to match within a collection
var validStatuses = new []{ "Pending", "Rejected", ... };
```

Then you would just need to update your `Where()` clause to check if your existing status matched any of those within your previously defined collection :

```
db.Updates.Where(c => !c.Sold && validStatuses.Contains(c.Status)))
```

Comment: ... thank you!  I knew there must be an easier way to do this, but Intellisense is shrieking.  Is there a syntax error in there?  I'm getting too crosseyed but I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Oyyy... of course.  Thank you!  I really should know better than to stay up too late beating my head against this kind of thing.  I'm very very grateful!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops. I was missing the braces to indicate the collection above was an array. That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

(c.Status.Equals("Pending") || c.Status.Equals("Rejected"))

```
var ud = db.Updates

         .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false) &&(c.Status.Equals("Pending") || c.Status.Equals("Rejected")))
         .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Rion Williams ... can I prevail upon your kindness one more time?  I realized that I need to make a change and my brain is melting.  The end result here is I need to retrieve the most recent entry from my table is it contains one of the array values.  This means that I need to apply that clause at the end (?) 

What I have so far follows:

Comment: var validStatuses = new[] { "Assigned", "Donor Called", "Dispatched", "Waiting" };

            var ud = db.Updates

               .Where(c => !c.Sold && validStatuses.Contains(c.Status))

             .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First()).ToList();

And it is returning multiple entries because the "Status" clause needs to occur after the date so that it returns the most recent entry only if the status is one from our array.

I'm sorry... can you help?

Comment: Man, I don't know if I got it.
Can you show the return and what you expect?

But, I think that the First() must be put after the Select().
Ex: 
Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp)).First()

Answer (score 0):

Try to use || or operator

```
   (c.Status.Equals(("Pending")|| c.Status.Equals("Rejected"));
```